# What is the difference between <nav> and <div>?

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have  a set of links, can I use `<div>` instead of `<nav>`?

```
<div>
  <ul>
   <li class="head_divider">...</li>
   <li class="head_divider">Text<br />Here</li>
   <li class="head_divider">...</li>
 </ul>
```

What is the difference between the two? they yield the same format/answer for me

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23238344/div-vs-nav-tag-with-css-positioning and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329739/difference-between-nav-vs-div-navbar-in-bootstrap and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628097/whats-the-difference-between-using-nav-and-div-around-bootstrap-3-navbars

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why to use HTML5 semantic tag instead of div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17272019/why-to-use-html5-semantic-tag-instead-of-div)

Answer (score 14):

- `<nav>` meant for more semantic markup (letting the browser know)
  that those links aren't just normal links, they are a navigation
  menu. This can be useful for accessibility (tabs, mobile
  devices,browsers, such as screen readers for disabled users, can use
  this element to determine whether to omit the initial rendering of
  this content.) and other things.

  For More reference on `<nav>` :
  https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sections.html#the-nav-element
- The `<div>` tag defines a division or a section in an HTML document.
  It is a block-level element that is commonly used to identify large
  groupings of content, and which helps to build a web page’s layout
  and design using CSS.

  For more reference on `<div>` : http://www.html-5-tutorial.com/div-tag.htm

When it comes to styling there is no big difference,

**[`<nav>`](https://jsfiddle.net/56L7520o/)**

**[`<div>`](https://jsfiddle.net/7kh63xyw/)**

Answer (score 2):

Technically they work the same way, but for search engines that tells them there is a navigation area.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others

Answer (score -1):

I've done an example of full semantic HTML markup a couple of years ago and published it on github.

Take a look at the code https://github.com/samad-aghaei/Semantic-HTML5/blob/master/index.html

```
<nav>
<ul itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemPage">
    <li>
      <a itemprop="url" rel="nofollow" href="#" title="Facebook" class="icon-facebook">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a itemprop="url" rel="nofollow" href="#" title="Twitter" class="icon-twitter">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a itemprop="url" rel="nofollow" href="#" title="Google Plus" class="icon-gplus">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a itemprop="url" rel="nofollow" href="#" title="LinkedIn" class="icon-linkedin">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a itemprop="url" rel="nofollow" href="#" title="RSS Feed" class="icon-rss-1">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

In HTML, the `<nav>` element is a semantic HTML5 element specifically designed to represent navigation links on a page. While you can use a `<div>` to create a similar structure, using `<nav>` provides better clarity and semantic meaning to your code. Semantically correct HTML helps browsers and other tools to understand the structure and purpose of your content, which can be beneficial for accessibility and search engine optimization.

Here's an example of how you could use the `<nav>` element for your navigation links:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="head_divider">...</li>
    <li class="head_divider">Text<br />Here</li>
    <li class="head_divider">...</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Using the correct semantic elements makes your HTML more readable and understandable for developers and tools, even if the visual result may appear the same.

If your links are not representing navigation and are, for example, just a list of related items, you might want to use a more generic container like `<div>`. However, if these links have a navigational purpose on your site, it's recommended to use the `<nav>` element for better semantic markup.

Comment: Did you create this answer with [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)?