# How we can make a difference between div and nav?

Tags: html, nav

there are two tags in html , one is div and another one is nav.. now I want to know the difference between these two tags according to their functions and roles...

I tried both the tag but I didn't found any unique difference between both, so I am expecting to get the detailed answer .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between <nav> and <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36097957/what-is-the-difference-between-nav-and-div)

Answer (score 1):

There are no such differences between "nav" and "div" unless the user is using a screen reader to access the website. As div is just a container while the screen reader understands when nav is used that this element contains
navigation links for accessing the website.